# Not able to get public channels

Tags: javascript, twilio

I am creating a small app using javascript SDK provided by twilio programmable chat , And I want to get the list of all the channels , To achieve this I am using getPublicChannelDescriptors() method.

below is the code:

```
$.getJSON(
    '/getToken?identity=' + identity + '&endpointId=' + endpointId,

    function (data) {

        console.log(data);
        chatClient = new Twilio.Chat.Client(data.token);

    chatClient.getPublicChannelDescriptors().then(function(channels) {

        //do something
    });
   }
 );
```

the error I am getting is below:

```
twilio-chat.min.js:149 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getChannels' of null
```

I am getting data in response of ajax call and able to create chatClient succesfuly and also I am able to fetch all the channels subscribed by the user by using method getSubscribedChannels() but not able to get public channels.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: [Try comparing your call with the example](https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/api-snippets/blob/master/ip-messaging/channels/list-public-channels/list-public-channels.js), just in case

Comment: I copied the code from the example itself

Comment: What is your `data` output? Another thing, make sure the setup is right (I know, but, just in case)

Comment: data is an object containing token I am getting from node server , And I think the setup is correct because every other method that I used is working fine.

Comment: Just token? Do you have a `channel` output?

Comment: Are you talking about data in chatClient?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168219/discussion-between-tico-and-akshay-aggarwal).

Comment: Did you find anything?

Comment: have same problem. need help

Answer (score 2):

Twilio has changed client constructor from v2.0. So you need to change it like:

```
Twilio.Chat.Client.create(token).then(client => {
// Use client
});
```

or

```
let client = await Twilio.Chat.Client.create(token);
```

This would fix the above problem.